# Real Estate Listing Scraper: How to extract # of bedrooms from listing title?

Tags: python, scraper

Python noob here so please feel free to assume that I don't know anything.

So I'm building this web scraper to go through real estate listings on a certain website, download them from a bunch of pages (each page is a different neighborhood), and pull the price and number of bedrooms from the listing title, ultimately putting all of these things into an Excel sheet that is easy for me to play with.

I've got all of those things working except for the bedroom count. Most of the listings use one of a handful of formats to communicate the number of rooms. So for example, if a listing was for a one bedroom apartment, you'd see one of the following strings in the listing text:

- 1br
- 1/one br
- 1/one bedroom

Easy enough. So I want this section of the script to go, "Does the listing title contain one of these strings? If so, it's 1 bedroom apartment. If not, check to see if it's a two bedroom apartment. If not, check to see if it's a 3 bedroom apartment. If it's none of these, just return a sad face."

My way of keeping the title text together with the number of bedrooms is to make a dictionary, where the key is the title text and the value is the bedroom count. This dictionary is called bedDict.

Below is what I've tried so far. Weird thing is, it SEEMS to work, but upon actual inspection, I see that there are alot of results are mismatched. A title that says "Beautiful 80sqm apartment 2 br close to the subway!" for example will say "1 br" in the "Bedroom Count" column of my spreadsheet.

The list 'goodLinks' contains all of the titles that I scraped from the classifieds site.

```
bedrooms = []
oneBrPat = ['1br', '1 br', '1 bedroom', 'one br', 'one bedroom']
twoBrPat = ['2br', '2 br', '2 bedroom', 'two br', 'two bedroom']
threeBrPat = ['3br', '3 br', '3 bedroom', 'three br', 'three bedroom']

print("Creating bedroom dictionary")
bedDict = {}
for b in goodLinks:
    bedDict[b] = ":("
#Setting the "values" to "sadface" and then replacing them with bedroom count after a match is found.
print("Beginning bedroom count")
for a in goodLinks:
    if a is not None:
    for b in oneBrPat:
        print(b)
        if str(b) in str(a):
            print (str(b))
            bedDict[a] = "1 br"
for a in goodLinks:
    if a is not None:
    for b in twoBrPat:
        print(b)
        if str(b) in str(a):
            print (str(b))
            bedDict[a] = "2 br"
for a in goodLinks:
    if a is not None:
    for b in threeBrPat:
        print(b)
        if str(b) in str(a):
            print (str(b))
            bedDict[a] = "3 br"
print("Ending bedroom count")

bedCount = bedDict.values()
```

The idea then is that "bedCount" will be the number of bedrooms, in order, which will be put into the Excel sheet alongside the prices and listing titles. Only problem is that the results in the Excel sheet don't match up with the actual post titles. What's up with that?

I can show more of the code if necessary, but the whole thing is 172 lines at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a regular expression for something like this as it could be designed to cater for more variations in your input list, for example additional spaces between words.

The following should get you started:

```
import re

tests = [
    "No bedrooms here",
    "Beautiful 80sqm apartment 1 br close to the subway!",
    "Beautiful 80sqm apartment one   br close to the subway!",
    "Beautiful 80sqm apartment 1  bedroom close to the subway!",
    "Beautiful 80sqm apartment TWO br close to the subway!",
    "Beautiful 80sqm apartment 2 bedrooms close to the subway!",
    "Beautiful 80sqm apartment 3 br close to the subway!",
    "Beautiful 80sqm apartment fOur br close to the subway!"]

d_numbers = {'one' : 1, 'two' : 2, 'three' : 3, 'four' : 4}

for test in tests:
    re_count = re.search("\s(\d|one|two|three|four)\s*?(?:br|bedroom|bedrooms)\s", test, re.I)

    if re_count:
        bedrooms_text = re_count.group(1).lower()

        try:
            bedrooms = int(bedrooms_text)
        except ValueError:
            bedrooms = d_numbers[bedrooms_text]

        print "Bedrooms:", bedrooms
    else:
        bedrooms = ':-('

    print "Bedrooms:", bedrooms
```

This would give you the following results:

```
Bedrooms: :-(
Bedrooms: 1
Bedrooms: 1
Bedrooms: 1
Bedrooms: 1
Bedrooms: 1
Bedrooms: 1
Bedrooms: 2
Bedrooms: 2
Bedrooms: 2
Bedrooms: 2
Bedrooms: 3
Bedrooms: 3
Bedrooms: 4
Bedrooms: 4
```

It might need further enhancement based on your full data set.